# Add Adorner to Image in WPF RichTextBox when loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, adorner, adornerlayer

I have a RichTextBox control in an application I am developing which I am using along with a ToolBar to create a rich text editor.  One feature I have implemented is the ability for a user to insert an Image, now it worth noting at this point that the output from the RichTextBox is RTF.

When the user inserts the Image I am using the following code to add the image to the Document and then add a ResizeAdorner (example from here [RichTextBox Resizing Adorner](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41229dc6-6171-453b-82bc-f742f629e4f1/richtextbox-resizing-adorner)) to the Image which allows the user to resize.  When the user saves and loads the Document the size of the Image is persisted correctly.

```
private void BtnInsertImage_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = false;
    ofd.CheckFileExists = true;
    ofd.CheckPathExists = true;
    ofd.Filter = "Image files (*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp)|*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp";
    ofd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
    ofd.Title = "Insert Image";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ofd.FileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
                                 {
                                     CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
                                 };
        Image image = new Image();
        image.IsEnabled = true;
        image.Source = bitmap;
        image.Width = bitmap.Width;
        image.Height = bitmap.Height;
        image.Loaded += this.ImageOnLoaded;
        image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;

        InlineUIContainer container = new InlineUIContainer(image, this.rtbEditor.Selection.Start);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(container);

        var doc = this.rtbEditor.Document;
        doc.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
    }
}

private void ImageOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    var img = sender as Image;
    if (img != null)
    {
        var al = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(img);
        if (al != null)
        {
            al.Add(new ResizingAdorner(img));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem and question is that when the Document is loaded i am unable to figure out how to add the ResizingAdorner to the Images in the document.  I am using an attached property to load the document contents, the code below is the part that loads the document:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetDocumentXaml(richTextBox)));
var doc = new FlowDocument();
var range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);

range.Load(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);

richTextBox.Document = doc;
```

Could anyone help with how I can add the ResizingAdorner to any images in the loaded Document please?

Answer (score 2):

So I have worked out a way that I can add the Adorner to the Image in the Document through the SelectionChanged event handler and the following code

```
var inline = this.rtbEditor.CaretPosition.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward) as Inline;
if (inline != null)
{
    this.AddAdorner(inline.NextInline as InlineUIContainer);
    this.AddAdorner(inline.PreviousInline as InlineUIContainer);
}
```

And this is the AddAdorner method

```
private void AddAdorner(InlineUIContainer container)
{
    if (container != null)
    {
        var image = container.Child;
        if (image != null)
        {
            var al = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(image);
            if (al != null)
            {
                var currentAdorners = al.GetAdorners(image);
                if (currentAdorners != null)
                {
                    foreach (var adorner in currentAdorners)
                    {
                        al.Remove(adorner);
                    }
                }

                al.Add(new ResizingAdorner(image));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is probably not the most elegant way to achieve this but for me this works so I wanted to post this so that others can choose to use this if appropriate